# Is there a Visual Studio 2010 file preview tab plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins

Is there a Visual Studio 2010 plugin for the new "[preview tab](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2012/06/19/visual-studio-2012-new-features-preview-tab.aspx)" feature in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: I've spent a couple of hours and found nothing :/

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to do it by myself, but I have no expierience in doing VS extensions nor using EnvDTE API.

I've followed [Building and publishing an extension for Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/12/09/building-and-publishing-an-extension-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx) to create a new Visual Studio 2010 extension.

Then I added a Tools menu item with the VSPackage Builder designer, and used this code to try to imitate the behaviour.

I am not able to:

- Determine whenever a file is selected, so I have to do a loop.
- Open a file in already existing window.
- Change the window to be shown
  at the right.

I leave the code here, just in case someone else is interested on creating an extension. Hope (s)he has a better knowledge of VS Extensibility.

```
[Guid(GuidList.guidPreviewDocumentTabPkgString)]
public class PreviewDocumentTabPackage : PreviewDocumentTabPackageBase
{
    private DTE dte;
    private Document currentTab;

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        this.dte = this.GetService(typeof(_DTE)) as DTE;
        if (this.dte == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dte");
        }

        var applicationObject = (DTE2)GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE));
        var solutionExplorer = applicationObject.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer;

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            object currentItem = null;
            while (true) // To be improved
            {
                // Get selected items
                var items = solutionExplorer.SelectedItems as Array;

                // Only do logic if there is one file selected, no preview for multiple files.
                if (items != null &&
                    items.Length == 1)
                {
                    var item = items.GetValue(0);
                    if (currentItem == null)
                    {
                        currentItem = item;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Only show preview if the file is "new".
                        if (item != currentItem)
                        {
                            currentItem = item;

                            // Determine if is a c# file.
                            var realItem = (UIHierarchyItem)currentItem;
                            var itemName = realItem.Name;
                            if (itemName.EndsWith(".cs"))
                            {
                                // Get the file
                                var projectItem = (ProjectItem)realItem.Object;
                                var projectItemPath = projectItem.Properties.Item("FullPath")
                                                                    .Value.ToString();

                                // No already opened file.
                                if (currentTab == null)
                                {
                                    // Open the file and get the window.
                                    this.currentTab = this.dte.Documents.Open(projectItemPath);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // Todo: Open the file in the this.currentTab window.
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Avoid flooding
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        });
    }
}
```